# SharedPerferences doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use SharedPreferences in my app but it just doesn't seem to be working.

First, I declare SharedPreferences as a global variable in the activity where I'm planning to use them:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
```

Then I set the default SharedPreferences in onCreate:

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("urnikSp", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("schudeleDownloaded", false);
editor.commit();
```

I then change the boolean value when a certain action is completed:

```
prefs.edit().putBoolean("schudeleDownloaded", true).commit();
```

And then in the same activity (when it is restarted), I check for the boolean value in onCreate like this:

```
boolean schudeleDownloaded = prefs.getBoolean("schudeleDownloaded", false);
if (!schudeleDownloaded){
    new PopulateDatabase().execute();
}
```

And even though I clearly set the new value to "true" upon completing a certain action, the IF statement you see above still executes because the boolean value still seems to be false.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to be correct... are you sure this code is the one you've written?

Comment: Please post your whole onCreate() function.

Comment: I'd say that your activity is destroyed and the second time the onCreate is called setting it to false.

Comment: Is this just a program flow issue? You say you set the default in onCreate() to false. Do you always do that before checking it?

Comment: Maybe the problem is not here. Are you sure that `onCreate()` is being called when you think it is? This is only my guess but I think that you really need to move this to the `onResume()`.

Comment: This code, with exactly this sequence works on my Nexus 4 with CM11 - please show the whole onCreate() so that we can see the full picture.

Comment: I solved it, I was setting the value back to false every time onCreate started because I was calling "putBoolean" in onCreate. I haven't used SharedPerferences much yet so it was a common mistake. Thanks for all the answers and comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are recreating your activity, the onCreate() method will be called again, so I think you change his value back to false

Answer (score 0):

Let me do a wild guess. Because when you restart, you set it to false again.... It is in onCreate function.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a separate SharedPreferences.Editor instance. So instead of doing this:

```
prefs.edit().putBoolean("schudeleDownloaded", true).commit();
```

Try this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("schedeleDownloaded", true);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. I use the first method regularly. The second method will also work but that isn't the casue of the problem

Comment: @ScouseChris Hmm. I actually fixed a problem with the SharedPrefernences not committing like this. But it might've been related to an earlier android version? I'll check if I can find the answer because I asked it on SO at the time to. This answer actually helped me trough the problem.

Comment: Interesting, the methods on `SharedPreferences.Editor` should all return the instance of that editor so you can chain calls exactly like in your initial code.

Comment: I'm referring to the top answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852576/android-shared-preferences-not-working

Comment: @ScouseChris I do however realize that this is not the issue.

Comment: yes I see what you mean, when commit is called all pending edits are saved to disc so creating new editors each time will mess up your edits. If the editor were made a local variable, or accessed in different methods after a wait e.g. comms then it shouldn't be the problem here.